# How do I start a new line in an giant set set? I tried all environments

Tags: formatting

I have say

> $$\left { Giant matrices : I have long conditions \right }$$

I tried use align, multiline, and split environments, but I cannot start a new line \ inside the set.

Example, I get error if I do

> > $$\left { Giant matrices : \\ I have long conditions, I get errors if I put \ inside the set \right }$$

Here is a dumb example

```
$$\left \{ \begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix} : A \in \{ \begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}\}, B \in \{\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}\} \right \} $$
```

Comment: 1) Don't use `$$  … $$` for displayed equations. Use `\[ … \]` instead. 2) Could you post a concrete example? 3) Anyway the syntax you use or the syntax I suggest, are for one-lined displayed equations.

Comment: @Bernard, sure hang on.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this? The code nests an `aligned` environment inside a `multline*` environment. I use a tall straight line to denote conditioning, rather than a potentially puny-looking `:` symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\bmat{%
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 &0  &0  &0 \\
  0 &0  &0  &0 \\
  0 &0  &0  &0 \\
  0 &0  &0  &0
  \end{bmatrix}}
\newcommand\bigstrut{{\vphantom{\mathstrut^{\mathstrut}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
  \left\{ \bmat,\bmat^\bigstrut \: \right\vert \\
  \begin{aligned}
        A &\in      \left\{\bmat,\bmat,\bmat,\bmat\right\}, \\
  \quad B &\in \left. \left\{\bmat,\bmat \right\}^\bigstrut 
               \right\}
  \end{aligned}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution, with a code adapted  from `mathtools` documentation. I define a `\set`command, based on the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command. This defines a `\set*` command, with an implicit `\left … right` pair in front of the braces, and a correct spacing.  For fine-tuning, `\set` accepts an optional argument: `\big`, `\Big`, &c. Using  Sébastien Gouezel's `\MTkillspecial` command makes this construction breakable across lines.

For your example to not overflow  the right margin , I used the `medsize` environment from `nccmath`. A last example makes the example one-lined, using the mathtools extensions to the `smallmatrix` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} %
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}

\newenvironment{bmmatrix}{\medsize\bmatrix}{\endbmatrix\endmedsize}

    \newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
    \bgroup
    \catcode`\&=9
    \let\\\relax%
    \scantokens{#1}%
    \egroup
    }
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter\set\{\}
    \reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\set{star}{
    \mathopen{#1\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
    #2
    \mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \set*{ \begin{bmmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix},\begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix} : {}& A ∈ \set*{ \begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix}, \begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix},\begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix},\begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix}}, \\%
  & B ∈ \set*{\begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix}, \begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix}} %
  }%
\end{align*}
\bigskip
\begin{align*}
  \set*{ \begin{bmmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix},\begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix} : A ∈ \set*{ \begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix}, \begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix} , \begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix},\begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix} & }, \\%
  B ∈ \set*{\begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix} , \begin{bmmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmmatrix} & } %
  }%
\end{align*}
\bigskip
\[
  \set[\Bigg]{ \begin{bsmallmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bsmallmatrix},\begin{bsmallmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bsmallmatrix} : A ∈ \set*{ \begin{bsmallmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bsmallmatrix}, \begin{bsmallmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bsmallmatrix},\begin{bsmallmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bsmallmatrix},\begin{bsmallmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bsmallmatrix}}, B ∈ \set*{\begin{bsmallmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bsmallmatrix}, \begin{bsmallmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bsmallmatrix}}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is line-breaking automatic here? I mean, what would happen (especially with the unmatched braces), in case `A\in loong list` would break into two lines?

Comment: No, it's not automatic. Automatic line-breaking can be done by the `breqn` package, but I didn't test to see what happens.

Comment: @Matsmath: I've checked. Independently from `nccmath` conflicting with `breqn`, it happens that it does not always break lines at the correct place: `A`, for instance is  alone in a  line above `∈`, and similarly for `B`.

Comment: The show frame environment is displaying a border around everything...kind ruined my document here. Anyway to hide it?

Comment: Remove the package. It's used to check everything fits within the margins, not for final versions of documents.

Comment: The code is a little too big for my stupid example. Can you tell me what adjustments you made? With a smaller example?

Comment: I  just replaced  `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` with `\usepackage{geometry}`, which removes the border.

Comment: Arg why can't I add an index for example \{ \}_{index}. I get noting displayed.

Comment: I have no problem to add an index. Could you post a non-working example?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ 0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmatrix} : A \in { \begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmatrix}},\right.\\
\left. B \in {\begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \\ &0 &0 &0 \end{bmatrix}} \right \} 
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```